# How to set hslider alignment in flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.6

I am working with Flex 4.6 AIR application. I have used mx slider but there is a problem in alignment. The slider should alignment and start below the 0 min. and end 60 min but slider is starting middle of the 0 min. and end middle of the 60 min lable.

The code is below.

```
<mx:HSlider id="timeSlider" width="168" change="timeSlider_changeHandler(event)"
                        dataTipFormatFunction="timeDataTipFunction" dataTipPrecision="0"
                        labelOffset="2" labels="[0 min.,60 min.]" liveDragging="false" maximum="60"
                        minimum="0" showTrackHighlight="true" snapInterval="1" styleName="hslider"
                        value="{uservo.showtime}"/>
```

The screen shot is below

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you say "alignment" do you mean the position of the slider thumb? Or are you really referring to how this component is aligned with other sibling objects? You might include a screen shot. I think you might need a few more reputation points to include an image attachment, so here is an up vote!

Comment: Have you checked http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d95.html ?

Comment: HI, Sunil D Thanks for adding reputation point. I have uploaded the image now you can clearly understand my problem. i want slider should start below the 0 and end in last below 60 min.

Comment: So to further clarify: the labels "0 min" and "60 min" are centered over the start/end points of the slider track (the horizontal bar). But you would like the slider bar to be a little longer so it goes to the begin/end of the labels? This might be easier to do with a Spark slider (`<s:HSlider>`) than with the MX version, because it's so much easier to modify Spark skins.

Comment: If I increase the width of this horizontal bar, The problem remains same. I want to achieve this using mx. Could you please arrange a code for it, This will be useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you want to get this effect set the following property to 0

```
trackMargin="0"
```